# Front-End hangs up for a while when I type quotation mark " in front of an image

Tags: bugs, front-end, image, system-performance, undo

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3747200] was created
>
> Thank you for taking the time to send in this report. I understand that when you put a quotation mark in front of an inline image, it makes the front end hang for a while. I have been able to confirm this behavior, and I will forward an incident report to our developers regarding this issue. Thank you for bringing this to our attention.

---

Run `ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]` or get an image into your notebook in some other way.

Now type `"` in front of it. Then delete it. Then write it again...

You will notice that *the front-end hangs* for quite some time when you type or delete the `"` (except for the first time?). (The image also gets a bit smaller when `"` is in front of it, but I think this is just the usual formatting.)

It hangs for a longer time when the image is bigger.

I lost some progress in notebook for this because I didn't expect it to **ever** recover (I was working with full size digital camera images).

Can someone confirm this?

`$Version === "11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"`

I think this is a large enough inconvenience to be worth reporting.

Comment: The bug isn't present in versions 11.3 and 12.0.

Answer (score 4):

I confirm the hang-up (except for the first typing of `"`) with versions 11.1.0, 11.0.1, 11.0.0, 10.4.1 on Win7 x64. With the process monitor I see that the FrontEnd's *closed memory* goes from 57 Mb to 71 Mb and backward during the hang. With version 8.0.4 the hang-up doesn't happen.

The workaround is to switch off the front end's interactive undo/redo system:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {UndoOptions, "Enabled"}] = False;
```

After evaluating the above line the hang-up disappears. But I strongly suspect a bug or at least significant imperfection here because there is no hang-up when you type `"` for the first time with enabled `Undo`. Please report it to the tech support.

Comment: I reported it...